# How can I pass an array from one function to another in a class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to set up a note-taking app using Node and Express.  Right now whatever note is saved overwrites what is in the db.json file.  I am trying to push whatever is already in the db.json to an empty array, push the most recent note and then write the file using that final array.  Does anybody have any tips on what I am doing wrong here?  Thank you.

```
  read() {
    return readFileAsync(path.join(__dirname, "db.json"), "utf8");
  }

  write(note) {
    return writeFileAsync(path.join(__dirname, "db.json"), JSON.stringify(note))
  }

  getNotes() {
    return this.read().then(notes => {
      var notesObject = JSON.parse(notes);
    });
  }

  addNote(note) {
    const newNoteArray = [];
    const { title, text } = note;
    if (!title || !text) {
      throw new Error("Note 'title' and 'text' cannot be blank");
    }
    const newNote = { title, text, id: uuidv1() };;
    return this.getNotes()
      .then(notes => {
        newNoteArray.push(notes);;
      })
      .then(newNoteArray.push(newNote))
      .then(this.write(newNoteArray));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 addNote(note) {

    const { title, text } = note;
    if (!title || !text) {
      throw new Error("Note 'title' and 'text' cannot be blank");
    }
    const newNote = { title, text, id: uuidv1() };
    return this.getNotes()
      .then(notes => {
        notes.push(newNote);
        return this.write(notes);
      })
  }
```

You don't need a `then` for simple synchronous actions like pushing an item into an array.  You only need `then` for promises.

Comment: This is working for me.  Thank you for the explanation.  Looks like I was overcomplicating things as I don't fully understand JavaScript at this length.

Comment: @butthash3030 you're welcome.  Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Just by upvoting?  It is telling me my vote is recorded but doesn't publicly display the score due to my low reputation.

Comment: @butthash3030 Hmm, you should be able to accept the answer even though you're new.  See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for help.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the content of your `writeFileAsync` function I can’t give you an exact answer but the issue is that you’re most likely overwriting the file content instead of appending to it. [check out this quick tutorial on how to write and append contents to a file](https://egghead.io/lessons/node-js-write-or-append-to-a-file-in-node-js-with-fs-writefile-and-fs-writefilesync)

Comment: That function is ```const writeFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)```
That was starter code for an assignment I am doing, so I am wondering if they want us to do it in some way that doesn't involve appending..

Comment: Fs.writeFile will overwrite the content, use fs.appendFile instead

Comment: I think the point of confusion is that your `var notesObject = JSON.parse(notes);` assigns the value to a local varible `notesObject` and then throws it away.  It also may be happening later than you think.  Try putting some `console.log`s in there.

Comment: Yes, when i put a ```console.log``` directly after, nothing shows up.    What is going on there?

Comment: I think he’s returning that value and then it’s passed into .then() callback as a param. @butthash3030 I’d recommend you watch that short tutorial I linked in my answer and if the answer helps please upvote and select as best, thanks!

Comment: Appending is working to add new arrays to db.json, but they are not rendering correctly since I'm guessing all the arrays need to be wrapped in one larger array. I need to mess around a bit more I guess.

Comment: I meant like this.
`var notesObject = JSON.parse(notes);console.log ("notesObject is", notesObject);`
You should see *something*.

Comment: Assuming that shows something sensible, you'll want to return `notesObject`.  Right now you're not returning anything so the promise will give you `undefined`.

Comment: Ok it is console logging the object as I'd expect it to be.  It is appending each entry into the db.json file but they are not rendering in a list like they should be.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you want to write the array as a single list in that file, a quick solution would be to read the content, convert from string to array, append new element and then write back to the file, this time overwrite the file using fs.WriteFile. I hope I’m understanding your problem otherwise I’m sorry if this answer is off. Cheers!